# How to select buttons by the text/html in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, button

I'm trying to select buttons by the text/html that appears on the button but with not success:

There are multiple button sets like this in my page:

```
<button>Save</button>
<button>Add</button>
<button>Cancel</button>
```

I've used the following:

```
$('button[value=Save]')
$('button[html=Save]')
$('button[innerHTML=Save]')
$('button[text=Save]')
```

But none of them works. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector like:

```
$("button:contains('Save')");
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. But why all the attribute selectors I used doesn't work?

Comment: @abacusit because you don't have these attributes on your button. If you would have <button value="Save">Save</button>, than it might work. Even that you can access some attributes like innerHTML and etc but these are just some sort of pseudo attributes

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

## 1: On selection of index

```
$('button').eq(0) // will select first
```

## 2: On selection of value

```
for(i=0;i<$('button').length;i++) {
   if($('button').eq(i).text() == 'Your text') {
       var myBtn = $('button').eq(i);
       break;
   }
}

$(myBtn).doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly navigating trough all of them is the solution:

```
$(function() {
    var buttons = $('button');
    buttons.each(function() {
        if( $(this).html() == "Save" ) {
            $(this).attr('style', 'background: red');
        };
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tqk6wuhu/